# Как удалить последние 4 строки в матрице?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, csv

Вод есть код мне нужно в module_3 сделать функцию которая удаляет в матрице(которая находится в файле) 4 последних строки, помогите пожалуйста

```
import csv
from matplotlib.pyplot import matshow, show
from module_1 import task_1
from module_2 import task_2
from module_3 import task_3
def read(csvfile):
    with open(csvfile, 'r') as file:
        r = list(csv.reader(file))
    for x in range(len(r)):
        for y in range(len(r[x])):
            r[x][y] = int(r[x][y])
    return r
def write(matrix, name = "result.csv"):
    with open(name, 'w') as file:
        for x in range(len(matrix)):
            for y in range(len(matrix[x])):
                if y == len(matrix[x]) - 1:
                    file.write(str(matrix[x][y]) + "\n")
                else:
                    file.write(str(matrix[x][y]) + ",")
t1 = task_3(read("tekst.csv"))
for x in range(len(t1)):
    print(t1[x], end=' ')
print('\n')
t2 = task_2(read("tekst.csv"))
for x in range(len(t2)):
    for y in range(len(t2[x])):
        print(t2[x][y], end=' ')
    print()
t3 = task_1(read("tekst.csv"))
for x in range(len(t3)):
    print(t3)
write(t2)
matshow(t2)
```

Вот module_3(данный код не работает, не понимаю как удалить строки)

```
def task_3(m):
    m[-int(4) + m]
    return m
```

Comment: Я бы давно ими воспользовался, но задание требует обойтись без них

Comment: `return m[:-4]` решает задачу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
def task_3(m, num=4):
    for _ in range(num):
        if m: m.pop()
    return m
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def task_3(m):
    m.pop(7)
    m.pop(6)
    m.pop(5)
    m.pop(4)
    return m
```